# Numbers with empty Korselt set

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Theorem:Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ be fixed distinct prime numbers, where $n\ge 2$. Then there exists an integer $q_0$ such that, for each prime number $q>q_0$, $N:=p_1p_2...p_nq$ has an empty Korselt set.

PROOF:Let $N=P_1q$, where $P_1=p_1p_2...p_n$ and $q$ be a prime number and greater than max$\{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$. Suppose that $N$ is an $\alpha$-Korselt number, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$, $Q:=gcd(\alpha,N)$ and $N=PQ$. Then, we have two cases.\
Case1: $q$ does not divide $Q$. By previous Proposition, we get $$q+1-\frac{N}{q}\le\alpha\le\frac{N}{q}+q-1,$$ which yields that $$1-P_1=1-\frac{N}{q}\le\alpha-q\le\frac{N}{q}-1=P_1-1,$$ hence, $\alpha=q+i$ such that $i\in\{1-P_1,2-P_1,...,P_1-2,P_1-1\}$. Let $j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, we have $p_j-\alpha$ divides $N-\alpha$, where $p_j-\alpha=p_j-q-i$ and $N-\alpha=P_1q-q-i=(P_1-1)(q+i-p_j)+(p_j-i)(P_1-1)-i$. It follows that $q+i-p_j$ divides $(p_j-i)(P_1-1)-i$. Thus, $q+i-p_j\le |(p_j-i)(P_1-1)-i|=|p_j(P_1-1)+(-i)P_1+i-i|\le |iP_1|+|p_j(P_1-1)|=|i|P_1+p_j(P_1-1)$. Hence, we get
\begin{equation}\label{eq:12}
    q\le |i|(P_1+1)+p_jP_1\le (P_1-1)(p_j+1)+p_jP_1\le {P_1}^2-1+{P_1}^2=2{P_1}^2-1.
\end{equation}
Case2: $q$ divides $Q$. Suppose that $\alpha=\alpha_1Q$ such that $gcd(p_j,\alpha)=1$. By Proposition \ref{prop3.11}, we get $$\frac{2Qp_j-N}{2Q-1}\le\alpha\le\frac{Qp_j+N}{Q+1}.$$ This yields $$\frac{2p_j-P}{2Q-1}\le\alpha_1\le\frac{p_j+P}{Q+1}.$$
As $P$ divides $P_1$, we get 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:13}
    -\frac{P_1}{2Q-1}\le -\frac{P}{2Q-1}<\alpha<\frac{p_j+P}{Q}<\frac{2P}{Q}\le\frac{2P_1}{Q}.
\end{equation}
Now, if we let $q$ be a prime number such that $q>2{P_1}^2-1$, then inequalities \ref{eq:12} and \ref{eq:13} do not hold. Indeed, under this assumption we have $-1<\alpha_1<1$, which implies that $\alpha_1=0$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha\neq 0$. So, for each prime number $q>2{P_1}^2-1$, $N=P_1q$ has an empty Korselt set.

Now, my question is how do I conclude that $-1<\alpha_1<1$